# Unable to Authenticate Users From Domain\Users Group

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate all users from a domain for my MVC application. At the moment I am testing with the user PC_NAME/Administrator.

I have tried authorising the user group from PC_NAME in my controller class as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433113/mvc-windows-authentication-allow-all-users-from-domain).

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "PC_NAME\\Domain Users")]
```

This doesn't work, I'm just prompted to login by the browser.

I have also tried this in web.config instead

```xml
<authorization>
      <allow roles="PC_NAME\Domain Users"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

This is also unsuccessful

---

For the record I tried authenticating just the Users role without specifying a domain, and I was able to access my site

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Users")]
```

It also works when I just specify a user name

```cs
[Authorize(User = "PC_NAME\\Administrator")]
```

How can I authenticate all users from a single domain (in this case VSD-PROMETHEUS)?

Comment: "This doesn't work, I'm just prompted to login by the browser." Well, to authorize you against the role, it needs to authenticate you, so why shouldn't it prompt you to login?

Comment: I would expect that you would only be prompted for a username/password if the initial authentication fails. For instance when authorising against the role User without the domain as mentioned above, I can successfully log in without being prompted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by creating a custom authorise attribute.

```cs
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

/// <summary>
/// Authorises User based on what domain they are on.
/// </summary>
public class AuthorizeDomainAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List of domains to authorise
    /// </summary>
    public string[] Domains { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        // Get the domain part of the username
        string userDomain = httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Substring(0, httpContext.User.Identity.Name.LastIndexOf('\\'));

        // Check if the user is on any of the domains specified
        foreach(string domain in this.Domains)
        {
            if (userDomain == domain)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Otherwise don't authenticate them
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then using this attribute on my controller.

```cs
[AuthorizeDomain(Domains = new[] { "PC_NAME")]
```